test a function that imports a class
lets say i have the file:
import { Client } from '@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js';
import logger from '@common/utils/logger';

interface TimezoneObj {
  timezone: string;
  timezoneName: string;
}

// Instantiate the Google Maps client once at the top level
const client = new Client({});

export const getGeocodeResult = async (address: string) => {
  const fN = 'getGeocodeResult';
  logger.info(`${fN} - Getting geo code data for address: ${address}`);
  
  const result = await client.geocode({
    params: {
      address,
      key: process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API || ''
    }
  });
  console.log(result);

  return result.data.results[0];
};

I was trying to create a test using jest for the function but i keep on failing. for some reason the mock i am doing is not really being mocked and result just ends up being undefined. how can i fix this?
here is an the latest failure of my jest test:
import { mockGeocodeResponse } from '@mocks/google-maps';
import * as mapService from './map.service';
import { Client, GeocodeResponse } from '@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js';

jest.mock('@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js');

describe('Map Service', () => {
  let client: Client;

  beforeEach(() => {
    client = new Client({}) as jest.Mocked<Client>;

    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  describe('getGeocodeResult', () => {
    it.only('should use the API key from the environment variable', async () => {
      process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API = 'test-api-key';

      jest.spyOn(client, 'geocode').mockResolvedValueOnce(mockGeocodeResponse);

      const result = await mapService.getGeocodeResult('123 Test St, Test City, TX');

      expect(client.geocode).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        params: {
          address: '123 Test St, Test City, TX',
          key: 'test-api-key'
        }
      });
      expect(result.formatted_address).toBe('Test Address');
    });
  });
});



It would be much easier if you provided the instance of the Client to your module, instead of letting the module instanciate it itself

was able to solve it using a test such as:
import * as mapService from './map.service';
import { Client } from '@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js';

// Create a mock implementation of the Client class
const mockGeocode = jest.fn();
const mockReverseGeocode = jest.fn();
const mockTimezone = jest.fn();
const MockClient = Client as jest.MockedClass<typeof Client>;

describe('Map Service', () => {
  const mockApiKey = 'mock-api-key';
  const mockAddress = '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA';
  const mockLatitude = 37.422;
  const mockLongitude = -122.084;

  beforeAll(() => {
    process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API = mockApiKey;
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    MockClient.prototype.geocode = mockGeocode;
    MockClient.prototype.reverseGeocode = mockReverseGeocode;
    MockClient.prototype.timezone = mockTimezone;
  });

  describe('getGeocodeResult', () => {
    it('should return geocode result for a given address', async () => {
      const mockGeocodeResponse = {
        data: {
          results: [
            {
              formatted_address: mockAddress,
              geometry: { location: { lat: 37.422, lng: -122.084 } }
            }
          ]
        }
      };

      mockGeocode.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockGeocodeResponse);

      const result = await mapService.getGeocodeResult(mockAddress);

      expect(mockGeocode).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        params: { address: mockAddress, key: mockApiKey }
      });

      expect(result).toEqual(mockGeocodeResponse.data.results[0]);
    });

    it('should throw an error if the geocode API call fails', async () => {
      mockGeocode.mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('Google Maps API error'));

      await expect(mapService.getGeocodeResult(mockAddress)).rejects.toThrow(
        'Google Maps API error'
      );
    });
  });


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
